# How do I define custom conditions for a kotlin `when` expression

Tags: kotlin, conditional-statements

I am trying to use the [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) in Kotlin to conditionally perform different logic given different cases for a value. Some of the cases are straightforward, eg. "when the value is null", "when the value is equal to X", but I have at least one case which is more involved, where I need to call another function to tell me whether or not it matches, eg. "when the value matches my predicate".

A simplified example from my specific case, the object being considered is an Instant type, and I have different cases for handling it as it compares to `Instant.now()`. In reality it is a nested field whose timestamp I am comparing in some cases, and other fields in other cases.

```kotlin
val timestamp: Instant? = myOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnInstant()
val result = when (timestamp) {
  null -> "result when timestamp is null"
  isInThePast(timestamp) -> "result when timestamp in the past ${timestamp.epochSecond()}" // <- question regarding the condition on this line
  else -> "result when timestamp is in the future ${timestamp.epochSecond()}"
}
```

I can get that to compile given a function defined called `isInThePast(timestamp: Instant?): Instant`. But since the return type it wants is `Instant` and not `Boolean`, I don't understand how I need to implement this function to capture specific values in the condition (ie, `timestamp.isBefore(Instant.now())`).

I am more experienced with java, thinking of a `Predicate<Instant>` functional, but not sure how (or if?) that can fit in with the Kotlin `when` conditional. More verbose ways do come to mind, but my question is whether `when` supports this type of condition, and if so how do I implement the expression to do so?

**edit**, to add some prior research:

Having found mostly only basic examples of how to use `when` including the `is X` and `in X` conditions, the following is a snippet from https://superkotlin.com/kotlin-when-statement/ that leads me to believe this is possible, but does not expand or provide the relevant code for me to see.

> ```kotlin
> var result = when(number) {
>     0 -> "Invalid number"
>     // OK: check returns an Int
>     check(number) -> "Valid number"
>     // OK: check returns an Int, even though it accepts a String argument
>     checkString(text) -> "Valid number"
>     // ERROR: not valid
>     false -> "Invalid condition"
>     else -> "Number too high"
> }
> ```

In the above example, what could `check(number)` and `checkString(text)` look like?

Comment: Have been looking for the same design since it kind of feels intuitive to work like that. Haven't seen a language feature request for it yet or discussions. Would appreciate. any links if there are. But having different types in the when might be difficult with design. Just different check operators inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `when` statement either has an argument (in parentheses before the braces) or it doesn't.

When you supply an argument you are limited to equals/is/in checks rather than arbitrary Boolean expressions. What these all have in common is implicitly using the argument to evaluate to a resulting Boolean.

When you don't supply an argument, you can use arbitrary expressions that evaluate to Booleans. So if you want arbitrary expressions, you cannot have an argument, and you must therefore spell-out your equals/is/in comparisons, for example:

```
val result = when {
  timestamp == null -> TODO()
  isInThePast(timestamp) -> TODO()
  else -> TODO()
}
```

---

Edit: Just a fun hack I thought of, not really serious, but you could create an object that you can use for an `in` check so you could still use the when statement with argument like this:

```
object ThePast {
    operator fun contains(instant: Instant) = instant.isBefore(Instant.now())
}

// ...

when (timestamp) {
    null -> TODO()
    in ThePast -> TODO()
    else -> TODO()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get your question but this is what I understand

```
val timestamp: Instant? = myOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnInstant()
fun isInThePast(value : Instant) : String{
    return when {
        value.isBefore(Instant.now()) -> "result when timestamp in the past ${value.epochSecond}"
        else -> "result when timestamp is in the future ${value.epochSecond()}"
    }
}
val result : String  = when (timestamp) {
    null -> "timestamp is null"
    else -> { isInThePast(timestamp) }
}
```

> OR

```
val timestamp: Instant? = myOtherFunctionThatReturnsAnInstant()

val result : String  = when (timestamp) {
    null -> "timestamp is null"
    else -> {
        when {
            timestamp.isBefore(Instant.now()) -> "result when timestamp in the past ${timestamp.epochSecond}"
            else -> "result when timestamp is in the future ${timestamp.epochSecond()}"
        }
    }
}
```